# Rails Active Record Query and JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I have the following models in my Rails application:

```
class Transaction 
  belongs_to :category
  has_one :group, :through => :category

class Category
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :transactions

class Group
  has_many :categories
  has_many :transactions, :through => :category
```

In my controller is the following:

```
 @transactions = Transaction.includes(:category, :group).group("groups.id").sum("amount")
 respond_to do |format|
  format.json{
    render :json => JSON.generate(@transactions.as_json(:include => [:category, :group]))
  }
 end
```

This produces the following json (**A**):

```
 {"1":2000,"3":5000,"2":1000}
```

However, my goal is to produce something like this (**B**):

```
 [{"group_id":1,"amount":2000},{"group_id":3,"amount":5000},{"group_id":2,"amount":1000}]
```

Any help on how I can go from **A** to **B** would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def user_transactions
  @transactions = Transaction.includes(:category, :group).group("groups.id").sum("amount")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json => custom_json_for(@transactions)
    end
  end
end

private
def custom_json_for(value)
  list = value.map do |k,v|
    { :group_id => k,
      :amount=> v    
    }
  end
  list.to_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, that gives me the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'group_id' for [1, 2000]:Array`

Comment: replace `group_id` with the column name of your table that you want it for.

Comment: I got your answer to work if I change it to: `list = value.map do |k, v|
    { :group_id => k,
      :amount => v    
    }
  end`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot a JSON-serialization, I would recommend you to take a look at ActiveModelSerializers:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers